# Get position of a character within a string using a pointer

Tags: c++

I want to get the position of a character within a string I have by searching for that character in the string using `strchr` and storing that into a pointer `*p`.
So for example:

```
char v[] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz", *p;
p = strchr(v, 'c');
```

In this particular scenario, would the `p` pointer hold the value `2` because `c`'s position is 2 inside of the string?

Comment: How does that have an "oop" tag? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As other answers indicate that returns the address of c, a quick test would be to make it print out the value:

like so:

```
std::cout << p << std::endl;
std::cout << *p << std::endl;
std::cout << p - v << std::endl;
```

The results you will get are:

```
cdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
c
2
```

Answer (score 3):

No. It gives you the *address* of the element at that position.

`p - v` (the difference between two pointers) will have the value 2, and *type* `std::ptrdiff_t`.

The type is important: it is guaranteed to have an adequate size for storing the difference between two pointers.

Answer (score 2):

Citing the [documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strchr/):

> Returns: A pointer to the first occurrence of character in str. If the
>   character is not found, the function returns a null pointer.

This is kinda self-explanatory. It does not return position, but rather an address.

As @Bathsheba said, you can use pointer difference to calculate the actual position in a string. Or use `std::distance` instead.

Answer (score 0):

> Return value : Pointer to the found character in str, or a null pointer if no such
>   character is found.

In your case `p` will be a pointer pointing to memory location of `c`.

```
std::cout << p;
```

**Output:**

```
cdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```